# update with a proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

It should be an easy one but I'm stuck

```
Proc sql; 

UPDATE dicofr 
SET    dicofr.period = correspondance.period 
FROM   dicofr 
INNER JOIN correspondance 
ON dicofr.name_fic = correspondance.name_fic;
```

I was thinking my update would be done but I got this error instead.

```
271  proc sql;
272  update dicofr
273  set dicofr.period = correspondance.period
           -
           73
           76
ERROR 73-322: Expecting an =.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

I've tried with a straight join with a `select`

```
proc sql;
SELECT * FROM dicofr INNER JOIN correspondance 
ON dicofr.nom_fic=correspondance.nom_fic;
```

The select is fine.

How come?

Is my SQL query not correct? I don't think so ...

**Edited**: It seems the update I want to do is not possible. Is there a way to do what I want with SAS language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SAS doesn't support JOINs in an UPDATE statement, for some reason.  You need to do it through a nested select.

```
proc sql;
update tableA A
set var=
  (select var 
  from tableB B 
  where B.id=A.id)
where exists (
  select 1 
  from tableB B
  where B.id=A.id);
quit;
```

Comment: Cheers Joe. You are the man as always. I had a look on other forums and it is weird this non support.

I'm putting the solution I've created in the comment 

`proc sql;
     update dicofr as h1
     set period=(select period from correspondance as h2 where h1.name_fic=h2.name_fic)
     where name_fic in (select name_fic from correspondance);
quit;`

Comment: Btw Joe. Even if my initial question was with SQL, is there a way to do that on the SAS native language? If yes, can you give me a hint on how? 

Do you want me to create another question?

Comment: You can use `UPDATE` as a SAS statement, also, although it doesn't update the table in place; or `MODIFY` which does (using a format, perhaps).

Comment: Cheers Joe. I will do my due diligence.

Comment: My understanding, and @Joe can correct me if I'm wrong, is that `UPDATE` or `MODIFY` are typically slower than using a straight `PROC SQL` call.  Furthermore, the reason I think SAS doesn't support the `UPDATE ... JOIN` syntax is because Oracle doesn't support it either and they have to cater to the lowest common denominator.

Comment: There's nothing special about `PROC SQL` that makes it generally faster; it tends to vary based on what you're doing.  I don't know why Oracle would have anything to do with what is supported in `PROC SQL`; the syntax of `PROC SQL` is entirely internal to SAS.  If you are using `PROC SQL` to modify an external DBMS, it will convert the code to DBMS specific code, but there are plenty of things SAS allows that aren't allowed elsewhere (`GROUP BY` remerging, for example).

Comment: Note that you should additionally have a where clause at the end to only update those records of interest; otherwise, any mismatch will result in null values being set. E.g.: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableB B WHERE B.id = A.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yer you are taking a wrong approach. Try somthing like this:-

```
UPDATE dicofr INNER JOIN correspondance 
ON dicofr.name_fic = correspondance.name_fic; 
SET dicofr.period = correspondance.period 
WHERE cond....
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for your update. However, I think that SAS has limitation in term of SQL update. Cheers.