# SAS PROC SQL update with inner join

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

Last time I checked, this is completely legit SQL code that even Access can handle. Not sure why I'm getting the following error from SAS

```
UPDATE fu_coding 
INNER JOIN old_form16 
    ON fu_coding.CSPCCID = old_form16.CSPCCID 
SET fu_coding.CHANGED = 1
WHERE fu_coding.NEW_DIAG <> old_form16.NEW_DIAG;
```

Error is:

```
18311      INNER JOIN old_form16
           -----
       22
       76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, (, '.', AS, SET.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629793/update-with-a-proc-sql

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `proc sql` supports update with inner join.  You can do this:

```
UPDATE fu_coding 
    SET CHANGED = (SELECT 1
                   FROM old_form16
                   WHERE fu_coding.CSPCCID = old_form16.CSPCCID AND
                         fu_coding.NEW_DIAG <> old_form16.NEW_DIAG
                  )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM old_form16
                   WHERE fu_coding.CSPCCID = old_form16.CSPCCID AND
                         fu_coding.NEW_DIAG <> old_form16.NEW_DIAG
                  ) ;
```

The code might be simpler using a data step.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error. SAS underlines the period between fu_coding and CHANGED. It says it's expecting an "="

Comment: @blacksaibot . . . That table alias is not needed there.

Answer (score 0):

SAS doesn't support update with inner join in the SQL procedure.  Either re-write (as per @Gordon's suggestion), or use [pass through](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001044413.htm) if possible!