# sql updating values according to same variable in another table

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I would like to update the values of “area” variable according to the new values of table B

my try:

```
update a set area=(select area from b)
where a.id=b.id
```

table A

```
Id   area
1      N
2      S
3      W
4     W
5     E
```

table B

```
Id   area
1      W
2      E
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
update a
  set area = b.area
from a
join b
  on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: @progster it should be without the `a.` Someone had edited my answer, but now I have corrected it.

Comment: now the error starts in "from". I am using the proc SQL, that is SQL inside SAS, don't know if it's the issue

Comment: @progster are your tables really named `a` and `b`?

Comment: @progster I tested the query in T-SQL (SQL Server 2012) and it worked fine. I wasn't aware you were using SAS. Perhaps you need to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24631197/390819

Comment: That is non-standard SQL In standard SQL there is no `join` or `from` clause for an `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
Update a set area= COALESCE((select b.area from b where a.id=b.id),a.area);
```

Comment: this overwrite everything in A, I want to update only what it is in B. now I see in A the values of area present in B and the rest is NULL

Comment: Try with Update a set area= COALESCE((select b.area from b where a.id=b.id),a.area);

Comment: this works thanks, the only issue is that in real life I have almost 100 variables to update with this criteria of a.id=b.id.   could be possible something more flexible? I don't know if it is possible to do this with joins

Comment: Yes, In any case you have to write that.